# Node with TS sending whole HTML AS text;

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, typescript

So i have a TS node server

The ts code is Like this:

```
import express, { response } from "express"
import fs from 'fs'
const app = express();

const home : Buffer = fs.readFileSync("/Users/divyanshundley/Documents/TS/public/index.html")

app.get("/",(req,res):void=>res.redirect('/home'))

app.get('/home',(req,res):void=>{
    res.end(home)
})

app.listen(9190,():void=>{
    console.log('server running on port 9190');
    
})
```

this is my type script code which is later compiled to js

but the webpage i see is this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>MAIN</title>
    <script src="./index.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="MAINHEADING">Hello</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

now this is the webpage content and i am seeing this a text now as elements what is the problem

[image]

Comment: Express has a sendFile method that makes this simpler. Currently you are not giving the correct MIME type for HTML, so your browser thinks it's plain text.

Comment: sendFile gives me an error saying it must be a buffer not a string

Comment: okay it is solved somehow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code was working but my browser was not